# what does wankyuu mean? kanji is 椀久

Tags: meaning

what does wankyuu mean? the kanji are 椀久 have tried many Japanese dictionaries but have come up empty also are there any resources that are better than jisho and the like for looking up Japanese? 
thanks in advance

Comment: https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%A4%80%E4%B9%85-665997 Any free online monolingual dictionary will be **far better** than jisho.

Comment: thanks for the link but it seems like the translations are in japanese

Comment: I still don't understand

Comment: 椀久{わんきゅう} is short for 椀屋{わんや}久右衛門{きゅうえもん}. I think this should help you unravel the mystery.

Comment: I'm asking because I'm trying to read 妾の会った男の人人 on aozora 椀久を出した　which I thought was getting it out but I don't know how you would get a person out

Comment: Maybe you could quote the text here so that the context is clearer. That way it would be possible to see whether an answer fits with the instance of the word you want to clarify.

Comment: http://aozora.binb.jp/reader/main.html?cid=57154　this is the url

Comment: 「鴈治郎が[新富座]{しんとみざ}で椀久を**出した** 」-- I think you should be asking the meaning of 出す...  The 出す here doesn't mean "get ~~ out".

Answer (score 2):

Checking https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%A4%80%E4%B9%85-665997, I found the following (my attempt at translation of that page).

Full name is 椀屋久右衛門 (wanya kyuuemon). A wealthy merchant from Midomae in Osaka. Had a love affair with the prostitute Matsuyama from Shinmachi. Ended up under house arrest? (座敷牢) after a life of wild excess. Died insane in the 5th year of the Enpou era (1677). Features in kabuki plays, shamisen recitations and musical performances.

Feel free to correct me.